# DocuSign API creates duplicate entries for the document

Tags: duplicates, docusignapi, status

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGhfb.png)

We have used DocuSign Rest API and at times we are seeing duplicate entries against one receiver in DocuSign account under "Sent Items". Though the receiver is receiving the email once only. See attached image for reference. What does the "waiting for others" status indicates and under which scenarios this status will be generated?

Comment: Can you share your code? are these created from templates? how many roles?

Answer (score 0):

`waiting for others` means that one or more of the signing recipients and/or certified copy recipients has not yet completed their action on the envelope.

The multiple rows in the `Sent` list means that you have sent the envelope more than once, you'll need to check your code to see how that is happening. I suggest that you have your code make a log entry every time your code calls the DocuSign eSignature API (and for create envelope calls, record the envelope id.)

If you can't figure out how your app is sending multiple envelopes when you expect that only one is being sent, use the [API Request Logger](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to see what is being sent to DocuSign from your app.

Re: only one email was sent even though there were two or more envelopes:

1. Using the DocuSign web app, examine the envelopes that are in flight to check their recipients. It could be that the email address is incorrect in some of the cases.
2. Check your email tool. The two email notifications for two different DocuSign envelopes will be very similar and are collapsed by some email agents.